# How to solve "TypeError: fn is not a function"?

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to implement Passport.JS and JWT functionality into my nodejs application and receive the following error

`TypeError: fn is not a function`

in this code block of my application

```
const utils = require('./utils')
const strategies = require('./strategies')

const pipe = (...functions) => args => functions.reduce((arg, fn) => fn(arg), args)

const initialiseAuthentication = app => {
  utils.setup()

  pipe(strategies.JWTStrategy)(app)
}

module.exports = { utils, initialiseAuthentication, strategies }
```

Would be awesome if someone could guide me in the right direction, as I am stuck here. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue myself. In the /strategies/index.js file I was exporting the strategy like so `module.exports = { strategy }`, but was calling `pipe(strategies.JWTStrategy)(app)` in the code snippet.

It has to be `pipe(strategies.strategy)(app)`.